# Converting an Sql query to LINQ

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, linq

I am trying to convert the below mentioned SQL query to LINQ query

```
Qry = "select Announcement, StartDate, Enddate,Annkey from
Announcements ";   Qry = Qry & " where Startdate <= #" & Today & "# " 
Qry = Qry & " and Enddate >= #" & Today & "# "  Qry = Qry + " order by
StartDate, Enddate";
```

What I have made so far -

```
public bool Selectdatafromannouncements()
        {


            List<Announcement> lstAnnounce = new List<Announcement>(
                from l in objVaccinationContext.Announcements
                where
                    l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                    && l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                orderby l.StartDate, l.EndDate
                select new (l.Announcement1, l.StartDate, l.EndDate, l.AnnouncementID)
                );


            return true;
        }
```

> Getting an error near select new ( as type expected please help me out i am a beginner with LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a constructor here, for creating the list.
The curly braces are used for creating anonymous objects, so instead of declaring lstAnnounce of `List<Announcement>` type, better use the var keyword.

So you can have this:

```
var query = from l in objVaccinationContext.Announcements
                  where
                    l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                    && l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                orderby l.StartDate, l.EndDate
                select new {l.Announcement1, l.StartDate, l.EndDate, l.AnnouncementID };
var lstAnnounce = query.ToList();
```

If you need a list of Annoucement objects:

```
var query = 
                from l in objVaccinationContext.Announcements
                where
                    l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                    && l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today
                orderby l.StartDate, l.EndDate
                select l;
List<Announcement> lstAnnounce = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `objVaccinationContext.Announcements` is a collection of `Announcement` objects, you don't need the anonymous type or to use the construct of List, you could just do:

```
List<Announcement> lstAnnounce = (
    from l in objVaccinationContext.Announcements
    where
        l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today && 
        l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today
    orderby l.StartDate, l.EndDate
    select l)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`select new (l.Announcement1, l.StartDate, l.EndDate, l.AnnouncementID)`

is wrong

try for Anonymous type:

```
select new {var1 = l.Announcement1, var2 = l.StartDate, vr3 = l.EndDate, var4 = l.AnnouncementID}
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ChildVaccinationDAL.ChildVaccinationContext.Announcement>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ChildVaccinationDAL.ChildVaccinationContext.Announcement>)' has some invalid arguments 
Getting this error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inserting items of an `anonymous` type into a list of `Announcement` when performing `select new (l.Announcement1, l.StartDate, l.EndDate, l.AnnouncementID)`.
What you need to do is explicitly create instances of `Announcement` type:

```
List<Announcement> lstAnnounce = 
objVaccinationContext.Announcements
                     .OrderBy(l => l.StartDate)
                     .ThenBy(l => l.EndDate)
                     .Where(l => l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today &&
                                 l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today)
                     .Select(l => new Announcement
                     {
                         Announcement1 = l.Announcement1,
                         AnnouncementId = l.AnnouncementId,
                         EndDate = l.EndDate,
                         StartDate = l.StartDate
                     })
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original query you use

```
Startdate <= Today  and Enddate >= Today
```

whereas your Linq has

```
l.StartDate.Value < DateTime.Today
&& l.EndDate.Value < DateTime.Today
```

Assuming your top query is what you are after, does this work for you:

```
 List<Announcement> lstAnnounce = 
            (from l in objVaccinationContext.Announcements
            where
                l.StartDate.Value <= DateTime.Today
                && l.EndDate.Value >= DateTime.Today
            orderby l.StartDate, l.EndDate
            select new Announcement
                 {
                     Announcement1 = l.Announcement1,
                     StartDate = l.StartDate,
                     EndDate = l.EndDate,
                     AnnouncementId = l.AnnouncementId
                 }).ToList();
```